# Hiding an Id in WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to hide an Id in WebView but for some reason it will not work. Does anybody know why? I am a beginner so sorry if it is a simple mistake:)
Best regards
getNordic

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.eventster.it");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsById('main-carousel2').style.display='none';})()");


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: What do you mean by hiding id? Can you explain more?

Comment: I mean the ID from the HTML-element. Like nearly every section in HTML has an ID and a class